# Google API Update Product details

Tags: google-api

Is there a way to update a product unsing

https://www.googleapis.com/content/v2/SKU/products

or any other scope without inserting all details again in the JSON?

Untill know I understand that as soon I use INSERT and the conditions

```
"channel": "online",
"contentLanguage": "de",
"offerId": "12345",
"targetCountry": "de",
"condition": "new"
```

are the same as in one existing product it updates the product.

But I want to avaid to upload every Attribut again and I dont have these data in my Programm in this moment so I would have to GET them each time from Google.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to update with INSERT but the ID must not be the SKU itself it must contain the JSON ID string(like): "online:de:DE:12345"

So a JSON like:

```
{
  "channel": "online",
  "contentLanguage": "de",
  "offerId": "online:de:DE:12345",
  "targetCountry": "DE",
  "price": {
    "value": "99.00",
    "currency": "EUR"
  }
}
```

Will UPDATE the existing product.